# Getting and setting class attributes in Dart / Flutter

Tags: flutter, class, dart

I would like to list a class's attributes and set them too. For example in a ListView when I tap on the value of an attribute I would like to increment it by 1.

Sample class:

```
class Person {
int age;
int height;
int weight;

Person({
this.age,
this.height,
this.weight,
});

}
```

Is it possible to list and set these values without writing getter and setter functions for each of the attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you code sample, you defined `age`, `height`, and `weight` as public. So, you don't need to define getters and setters. You can directly increment and decrement their values.

```dart
void main() {
  final a = Person(age: 25, height: 210, weight: 90);
  a.age++;
  a.height++;
  a.weight++;
  print(a);
  // This person is 26 years old, 211cm tall and weights 91kg

}

class Person {
int age;
int height;
int weight;

Person({
this.age = 0,
this.height = 0,
this.weight = 0,
});
  
toString() => 'This person is $age years old, ${height}cm tall and weights ${weight}kg';

}
```

However, you might encounter problems by mutating objects if later, you rely on state equality to rebuild a Widget. It's better to handle your State objects as being immutable.

Then, regarding listing the values, if you refer to `[dart:mirrors][1]`, it's not supported by Flutter.